# How to set a logarithmic scale across multiple ggplot2 contour plots?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colorbar

I am attempting to create three contour plots, each illustrating the following function applied to two input vectors and a fixed alpha:

```
alphas <- c(1, 5, 25)
x_vals <- seq(0, 25, length.out = 100)
y_vals <- seq(0, 50, length.out = 100)

my_function <- function(x, y, alpha) {
  z <- (1 / (x + alpha)) * (1 / (y + alpha))
}
```

for each alpha in the vector alphas, I am creating a contour plot of z values—*relative to the minimal z value*—over x and y axes.

I do so with the following code (probably not best practices; I'm still learning the basics with R):

```
plots <- list()

for(i in seq_along(alphas)) {
  z_table <- sapply(x_vals, my_function, y = y_vals, alpha = alphas[i])
  
  x <- rep(x_vals, each = 100)
  y <- rep(y_vals, 100)
  z <- unlist(flatten(list(z_table)))
  z_rel <- z / min(z)
  d <- data.frame(cbind(x, y, z_rel))
  
  plots[[i]] <- ggplot(data = d, aes(x = x, y = y, z = z_rel)) + 
    geom_contour_filled()
}
```

When alpha = 1:[image: alpha = 1]

When alpha = 25:

[image: alpha = 25]

I want to display these plots in one grouping using ggarrange(), with **one logarithmic color scale** (as relative z varies so much from plot to plot). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a data frame with all the data for all alphas combined, with a column indicating the alpha, so you can facet your graph:

I basically removed the `plot[[i]]` part, and stacked up the `d`'s created in the former loop:

```
d = numeric()
for(i in seq_along(alphas)) {
  z_table <- sapply(x_vals, my_function, y = y_vals, alpha = alphas[i])
  
  x <- rep(x_vals, each = 100)
  y <- rep(y_vals, 100)
  z <- unlist(flatten(list(z_table)))
  z_rel <- z / min(z)
  d <- rbind(d, cbind(x, y, z_rel))}

d = as.data.frame(d)
```

Then we create the alphas column:

```
d$alpha = factor(paste("alpha =", alphas[rep(1:3, each=nrow(d)/length(alphas))]),
                 levels = paste("alpha =", alphas[1:3]))
```

Then build the log scale inside the contour:

```
ggplot(data = d, aes(x = x, y = y, z = z_rel)) +
  geom_contour_filled(breaks=round(exp(seq(log(1), log(1400), length = 14)),1)) +
  facet_wrap(~alpha)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Edited a little to make the breaks a little cleaner: ```breaks=2^(seq(log2(1), log2(2048), length = 12))```